# does ios Auto-Renewable Subscriptions still need your own server?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I read some articles on SO and internet about Auto-Renewable Subscriptions, it seems you need your own server to implement it, but not sure those articles are up-to-date. the new apple doc is here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW6
but I can't draw a conclusion from it. also I noticed urban airship has dropped their support for IAP https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/1099036-in-app-purchase-sunset-migration-guide
they said "Starting in iOS 6, Apple has introduced content hosting as an iTunes Connect feature, which will allow application developers to deliver paid purchases entirely through StoreKit, avoiding many of the previous hassles involved in receipt verification and 3rd party download hosting.  "

so my question is do we still need a server to implement Auto-Renewable Subscriptions?
if not what's the workflow now?

Comment: I recently implemented Auto-Renewable Subs and work in still in progress. What own server you are taking about? you can validate a receipt with your server code or through your client code.

Comment: I had an impression that we used to need a server to validate a receipt. at least that's what I read in some past post. I don't know if it is still the case for current SDK.

Comment: I hope now we can bypass our own server and do it all from the ios app if it is possible